# How can I display Time to my game

Tags: java, swing, time

I have a falling square game that I am currently making. I need to have a score system, but I don't know how to integrate a and display that onto the game frame.

My question is how can I make a timer that counts upwards and display that in real time onto the frame of my game.

My code:

```
package GamePackage;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Game extends JPanel { 

    //changing these values will change the size of the game, while still remaining functional
    //within the size limit specified.
    public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 875;
    public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;
    private Timer countdownTimer;

    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTimer;
    private String Highscore = "";

    private int count;
    int Health  = 1;

    //Creates a Square object Array
    Square[] squareArray = new Square[20];
    //Triangle[] TriangleArray = new Triangle[10];

   Player thePlayer = new Player();


    public Game() {

        //initializes square objects

        for (int i = 0; i < squareArray.length; i++)
            squareArray[i] = new Square();


    }

     public static void music(){
        try{
            AudioStream Music = new AudioStream (new FileInputStream("/SplashDemoPackage/URF.wav"));
            AudioPlayer.player.start(Music);
        }catch (IOException error){}
    }

   private void StartGame(){
               count = 14;
         countdownTimer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               lblTimer.setText(Integer.toString(count));
               count = count -1;
               if(count<0){
               lblTimer.setText("0");
               }
         }
    });
    countdownTimer.start();
   }


    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {


        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //paints square objects to the screen


        for (Square aSquareArray : squareArray) {
            aSquareArray.paint(graphics);    
        }

      //   for (Triangle aTriangleArray : TriangleArray) {
      //      aTriangleArray.paint(graphics);    
       // }

        thePlayer.paint(graphics); 

  //      if(Highscore.equals("")){
//            Highscore = this.GetHighScore();
   //     }

    }

  //  public void DrawScore(Graphics g){
   //     g.drawString("Score: " + score, 0, B);
  //      g.drawString("HighScore: " + HighScore, 0,);
  //  }

    public void update() {

       // calls the Square class update method on the square objects
         if(Health > 0){

         for (Square aSquareArray : squareArray) aSquareArray.update();
         }

            // if(Health > 0){

        // for (Triangle aTriangleArray : TriangleArray) aTriangleArray.update();
        // }

    }



      private void mouseMove(MouseEvent evt) {
          if(Health > 0){
          thePlayer.PlayerMove(evt);  
         }
    } 


   public void collision(){
     Rectangle rectangle1 = thePlayer.bounds();//player rectangle 
     for (Square square: squareArray) { 
        if(square.GetBounds().intersects(rectangle1)){//testing all squares vs player
            Health = Health - 1;
           System.out.println("HIT");

             if (Health == 0){
                    System.out.println("LOST");

             }
        }  
    } 

      //    for (Triangle triangle: TriangleArray) { 
    //   if(triangle.GetBounds().intersects(rectangle1)){//testing all triangles vs player
     //       Health = Health - 1;
      //     System.out.println("HIT");

       //      if (Health == 0){
        //            System.out.println("LOST");

       //      }
      //  }  
   // } 

 }

 private static void GUI() throws InterruptedException {

        Game game = new Game();
        Player thePlayer = new Player();

        JLabel lblStart = new JLabel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Dodge The Squares");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);





         BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// Create a new blank cursor.
Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
    cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");

// Set the blank cursor to the JFrame.
frame.getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);



              frame.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mouseMove(evt); 
            } 

            private void mouseMove(MouseEvent evt){
                game.mouseMove(evt); 
            }
        });


        while (true) {
            game.update();
            game.repaint();  
            game.collision();


            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

 }

  public void DrawScore(Graphics g) throws InterruptedException{

        while (true) {
            int time = 0; 
           time = time + 1;
            g.drawString("Score: " + time, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT + 10); 

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

  }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         new Scoreboards().setVisible(true); 
        music(); 
            GUI();

    }       
}
```

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` will be your best friends from here on out ;)

Answer (score 0):

For game usages I would suggest System.currentTimeMillis() because it is better performance wise than System.nanoTime(). An example of how you could track the time in a game:

```
public class Stopwatch {
    private long startTime;

    public void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public float getElapsedTimeSeconds() {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000f;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.start();
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Time elapsed in seconds: " + stopwatch.getElapsedTimeSeconds());
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000);` will freeze a GUI if not used carefully. Better to use a Swing based `Timer` to update the GUI regularly.

Comment: I agree that you don't need or want the sleep(5000), but I don't think you'd need a separate timer for this - the program is already updating the GUI every 10 ms or so.

Comment: Apologies for ambiguity, the Thread.sleep call was only to demo the StopWatch functionality.